# Mostrar/Ocultar una fila spreadsheet al hacer clic

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy trabajando con una hoja de calculo para que tenga un estilo mas web y necesito mostrar detalles de algunos campos solo cuando el usuario lo requiera. Puedo mostrar una fila oculta con `sheet.showRows(3)` pero no logro ocultarla usando:

```
var clic=0;
function mostrarDetalle(){
 var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
 if (clic==0){
  sheet.showRows(3); 
  clic = 1;
 }else{
  sheet.hideRows(3);
  clic = 0; 
 }
}
```

Solo me funciona esto:

```
var sRows = sheet.showRows(3) || sheet.hideRows(3);
```

pero se oculta automaticamente y necesito que el usuario pueda controlar cuando se debe ocultar, pueden ayudarme?

Comment: En Google Apps Script las variables globales no son persistentes. Se "reinicializan" cada vez que se manda llamar una función desdes el botón ejecutar, una imagen, menú, panel lateral, diálogo o activador.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero no hay forma de hacerlo entonces? quizas un listener que indique si la fila se muestra o no?

Comment: Google Apps Script no tiene listeners como los que se pueden agregar elementos DOM, tampoco tiene un método directo para identificar si una fila está a la vista u oculta. Podrías agregar una columna auxiliar con una función subtotal.

Answer (score 1):

## Sobre el código en la pregunta

Dado que las variables globales se "reinicializan" cada vez que se ejecuta el script, no son apropiadas como almacenamiento persistente entre una ejecución y otra.

## Generalidades

Como se menciona en la pregunta los métodos para ocultar o mostrar una fila por su número de fila son

- showRows(numfila)
- hideRows(numfila)

Lamentablemente ni el servicio Spreadsheet ni Google Sheets API incluyen métodos para indicar si la fila está visible u oculta.

## Soluciones provisionales

### Del lado de la hoja de cálculo

- Se podría usar una columna para mantener una valor que indique se la fila se ha puesto visible u oculta
- Se podría usar fórmulas como `=SUBTOTAL(102,A1)` la cual devolverá 1 si A1 tiene un valor numérico y está a la vista y 0 si tiene un valor numérico y está oculta.

### Del lado de Google Apps Script

Se podrían usar propiedades del documento para guardar el estado de la fila

Lamentablemente las solucione provisionales anteriores no son confiables pues dependen de que el usuario use la hoja de cálculo de forma apropiada según fuera el caso.